# Problems with rider and xamarin.forms creating a solution cross platform using host linux system

Tags: linux, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, rider

I have Linux as my base system
but when creating a cross platform solution in rider
create the entire project,
but it gives me an error with the ios solution,
I understand that ios does not compile on linux and there are alternatives on windows and
the option to pair with a mac or use the cloud
but I only create the project and it won't let me update
the Android solution,
my question is
How can I create a Cross Platform solution and delete the iOS solution?
I understand I can create a Native Android solution, but that is not the case,
What files can I configure to remove the iOS solution? in a cross platform project, of course.

It also won't let me update Xamarin.Android.Support,
I tried to remove the iOS solution but it gives me an error.

[image: Newly created project]

[image: Trying to update xamarin forms in the project]

[image: Throws an error when you want to update]

Comment: just delete the entire iOS folder and edit the sln file to remove the reference

Comment: I just installed the Rider 2020 version and it does what you tell me, I remove the solution and remove the problem, thanks for your help.

Comment: close post, thanks @Jason